# MVC pattern controller vs model strategy

Tags: model-view-controller

Imagine a forum. You have Threads and Replies. Which controller and action would you use when the user clicks on a thread?

- `ThreadsController.Details(int threadId)`
- `RepliesController.Index(int threadId)`

The first option involves calling a service for fetching the replies and pushing them to the view. The second one a service for fetching the thread post.

Comment: You might want to try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CBauer Without more details and context, this would probably get closed as too broad or primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ThreadsController.Details(int threadId)